# as3 slope detection for non uniform terrains

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, terrain

I want to create a 2d game in which a car moves along the edge of an irregular shaped hill. I want to use basic as3 (no physics engine like Box2d or Nape). With a lot of research I found [this](http://acidleaf.com/as3-slope-detection-for-non-uniform-terrains/) thing which is exactly what i want but there is only the logic and no source code. Can someone help me with a piece of code that can do this in as3? Also suggest if there is a better alternative to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I myself don't have much knowledge into code like this, and I can't make a comment because I'm short 7 reputation :'( but the article you linked does have another link to a Worms-esque program with code that might be of help to you. [Here's](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/08/05/worms-like-destructible-terrain-in-flash-part-2/) a link to that site in question and I'll also provide some appropriate code that you can see if it's of use to you.

So this program has a listener for if any key is down and sets a boolean as true if it's a key your program is using (movement, space for jumping or whatever), that listener looks like this

```
    public function key_down(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.keyCode==37) {
            left_key=true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==39) {
            right_key=true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==32) {
            space_key=true;
        }
    }
```

And then it has a subsequent listener for when a key is released

```
    public function key_up(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.keyCode==37) {
            left_key=false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==39) {
            right_key=false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==32) {
            space_key=false;
        }
    }
```

And finally the stage has an ENTER_FRAME listener for moving the character that runs this function

```
    public function move_character(e:Event) {
        //If left key is pressed, we'll move the character to the left
        if (left_key) {
            for (i=0; i<3; i++) {//Do you remember when we made the character fall? We had to move the character pixel by pixel
                if (! terrain_bmpd.hitTest(new Point(terrain_bmp.x,terrain_bmp.y),0x01,new Rectangle(character.x-6,character.y-10,1,17))) {
                    character.x--;  /*If the character doesn't hit the ground, we can move left. However,
                                    the character may be sunk under the ground. We have to lift it*/
                    while (terrain_bmpd.hitTest(new Point(terrain_bmp.x,terrain_bmp.y),0x01,new Rectangle(character.x-5,character.y+9,10,1))) {
                        character.y--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (right_key) {//Well, that's the same for the right key
            for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
                if (! terrain_bmpd.hitTest(new Point(terrain_bmp.x,terrain_bmp.y),0x01,new Rectangle(character.x+5,character.y-10,1,17))) {
                    character.x++;
                    while (terrain_bmpd.hitTest(new Point(terrain_bmp.x,terrain_bmp.y),0x01,new Rectangle(character.x-5,character.y+9,10,1))) {
                        character.y--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (space_key&&! jumping) {//That's easy: if he isn't jumping and you press space, his speed will be negative and he'll jump
            character_speed=-10;
            jumping=true;//Now the character can't jump again
        }

        character_speed++;//Every frame we will increase character's speed
        if (character_speed>0) {
            //If the speed is positive, we will check a collision between the terrain and the rectangle below the character
            for (i=0; i<character_speed; i++) {//We check the collision pixel by pixel...
                if (! terrain_bmpd.hitTest(new Point(terrain_bmp.x,terrain_bmp.y),0x01,new Rectangle(character.x-5,character.y+9,10,1))) {
                    character.y++;//If there isn't a collision, the character will fall
                } else {
                    jumping=false;//If there's a collision with the ground, the character isn't jumping
                    character_speed=0;//The speed is 0, because the character hit the ground
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (i=0; i<Math.abs(character_speed); i++) {//If the speed is negative, the for loop won't work. We have to use Math.abs().
            //Now we will check the collision between the terrain and the rectangle above the character
                if (! terrain_bmpd.hitTest(new Point(terrain_bmp.x,terrain_bmp.y),0x01,new Rectangle(character.x-5,character.y-10,10,1))) {
                    character.y--;
                } else {
                    character_speed=0;//Well, that's the same: the character hit the ground
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry I couldn't provide any personal experience, if you want more then the article I linked above will provide more information.